# Job Scheduler in Android

Tags: android, scheduler

I am working on an application where user can set reminder for any task and there is start and end date for this reminder. All the information regarding task is stored in database. So I need to write scheduler which run after every 15 min and fetch details from database and check if user has set any reminder then app will give notification. I tried to search on google but most of the examples are using start and stop buttons. Can anyone help me to use proper way to call scheduler without any click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WorkManager to periodically perform a task. You can refer to the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/recurring-work

Sample Code:
Your worker class:

```
class YourWorkerClass(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters)
    : Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        // Do the work here--in this case, fetch data from database.

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Using WorkManager to schedule the Work:

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .build()

    val saveRequest =
    PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<YourWorkerClass>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(myContext)
        .enqueue(saveRequest)
```